# Bootstrap mobile change breakpoint issue

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap on a site I am developing and want to change the breakpoint of the mobile menu upward to a larger size.  I have managed to do most of this withoug a problem however, where the menu used to drop down on a hover event I now need to to work on a click event (like the smaller versions of the mobile menu).

I am not having much luck working out what is controlling the change between a hover event to a click event, can anyone elaborate on how this works in the bootstrap system?

The system as is at http://kjhire.co.uk/index

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I should have mentioned I am using Bootstrap v3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to add `.dropdown-menu` to media query as mentioned below.

style.css line 172

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
header .navbar-nav li.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {display: block;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this media query and change the break point value what you need.

```
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
.navbar-header { float: none; }
    .navbar-left,.navbar-right { float: none !important; }
    .navbar-toggle { display: block; }
    .navbar-collapse { border-top: 1px solid transparent; box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1); }
    .navbar-fixed-top { top: 0; border-width: 0 0 1px; }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse { display: none!important; }
    .navbar-nav { float: none!important; margin-top: 7.5px; }
    .navbar-nav>li { float: none; }
    .navbar-nav>li>a { padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; }
    .collapse.in { display:block !important; }

 }
```

Comment: No I have had that code in it that changes where the mobile menu appears and changes the menu to drop as a group full screen width, however any second level drop downs still react as a hover not a click event, this is my problem. Sorry my fault for not being clear on the secondary drop down.